# Looping a Cell Reference in a match function

Tags: vba, loops, reference, match, cell

I'm pretty new to VBA and was wondering why my formula doesnt work?

I'm trying to loop the cells `Sheets("Summary").Cells(11 + X, 13)` in my match function but it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Sub Reset()

Dim X As Integer

For X = 0 To 19

Sheets("Summary").Cells(11 + X, 13).Select
Selection.Formula = "=INDEX(YMAX!$A:$W,MATCH(Summary!$J$4&"" ""&Summary!$J$5&""     ""&11,YMAX!$B:$B,0),MATCH(sheets("Summary").cells(11 + x,9),YMAX!$1:$1,0))"

Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. You're asking your question wrong. What does "doesn't seem to work" mean ?

Comment: Write the first formula you want directly in the sheet, without a macro.  Does it work?  If Yes, include it here in your question. If No, you need to explain more what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the following errors

- &'s are in the wrong places (should be outside of the quotes when concatenating text, inside the quotes when concatenating cell references)
- Variables (i.e. your reference to a cell on the "Summary" sheet) do
  not need to be in quotes when building a string in VBA
- (not an error, per say) You don't need to do `.Select` as you can
  set the formula of the cell directly.

Update your code with the following

```
Sub Reset()

Dim X As Integer

For X = 0 To 19
    ' Broken up on several lines for clarity
    Sheets("Summary").Cells(11 + X, 13).Formula = 
        "=INDEX(YMAX!$A:$W,MATCH(Summary!$J$4" & " " & _
            "Summary!$J$5" & "    " & _
            "11,YMAX!$B:$B,0),MATCH(" & _
                Sheets("Summary").Cells(11 + X,9).Address & _
              ",YMAX!$1:$1,0))"

Next X

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if that's the formula you want exactly, but it's what i interpreted given your current code. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Awesome. If this answer works for you, you can also "accept" it by clicking the check next to this answer